# Enable multiplayer games with GameCenter between iOS and macOS players

Tags: ios, macos, game-center, multiplayer, multiplatform

I am trying to create a multiplayer game that is playable between iOS an macOS users.

To enable multiplayer gaming I make use of Apple's [GameKit framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gamekit) & [GameCenter service](https://developer.apple.com/game-center/) for matchmaking.

Initially I tried to use the same bundle id and at least then it was possible for players to find each other between iOS and macOS platforms, however Apple doesn't allow to use the same bundle id between iOS and macOS apps in the AppStore.

So now that I changed my bundle id for iOS to be different, it's not possible for iOS players to find macOS players anymore and vice versa when using GameCenter / GameKit.

I read up in the documentation and [there's supposed to be a "Multiplayer Compatibility" section](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/MatchmakingwithGameCenter/MatchmakingwithGameCenter.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH12-SW14) in AppStore Connect that should allow iOS and macOS to play against one another.

> In iTunes Connect, you can provide compatibility information that describes which versions of your game can see each other during the matchmaking process. Each compatible group of devices and versions of your game are matched as separate groups.
>
> The ability to create these matchmaking groups is quite flexible:
>
> - When you create a new version of a game (such as a bug fix), you can declare whether the new version is compatible with the older versions (and which ones, specifically).
> - You can create distinct games (with different bundle identifiers) and still allow them to play against each other.
> - You can create distinct games on both OS X and iOS and match them against each other.
>
> [image]

**However when I log in into AppStore connect this section seems to be gone.** I didn't find anywhere if Apple removed this functionality somewhere from AppStore connect.

So my question is, is it still possible to somehow enable this functionality for my iOS and macOS app?

***P.S.:** Adding the iOS and macOS bundle id's to the same group in AppStore Connect doesn't seem to work either. I guess these groups are only meant to share leaderboards and achievements between platforms?*